# Decision Tree Algorithm Suggestions

Tags: python, algorithm, decision-tree

I want to write a method that takes nearly 70 parameters, and returns a result according to inputs.

Here is the representation of logic of my algorithm:

[image: example-tree]

In representation, there are 7 parameters and as a result of tree, it gives us Y or N.

How can I accomplish to write an algorithm like that but bigger and more complicated? Which language would calculate this more efficient?

Comment: Please don't link external pictures, embed it here in your answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely uploading image is not working here. I tried to upload this, but it didn't show the image when it's clicked.

Comment: @AndrejKesely go click 'example-tree'. do you see the image?

Comment: Yes, now it's better.

Comment: Do you want to learn the structure of the tree and the decision thresholds at each node from a training dataset, or do you already know what you want and you just need to code it? When you ask for something *more efficient*, in what way does it need to be efficient - small code? fast execution?

Comment: @Georgy thanks for your advice. I will move it.

Comment: @nekomatic I already know the results according to each situation. I just want to write this algorithm more efficient means fast execution. The algorithm will take all parameters and direct it through the tree which is already determined. But the tree will be too big to calculate it with if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to have a Graph with Vertices where the Edge contains the condition that needs to be fulfilled to travel through it.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, edges, val = None):
        self.edges = edges
        self.val = val

    def decide(self, args):
        if len(self.edges) < 1:
            return self.val

        for edge in self.edges:
            (cond, next) = edge

            if cond(args):
                return next.decide(args)
                break

n_a_a = Node([], 'y')
n_a_b = Node([], 'n')
n_b_a = Node([], 'y')
n_b_b = Node([], 'n')

n_a = Node([(lambda args: args['B'] > 0, n_a_a),
            (lambda args: args['B'] <= 0, n_a_b)])
n_b = Node([(lambda args: args['B'] > 5, n_b_a),
            (lambda args: args['B'] <= 5, n_b_b)])

root = Node([(lambda args: args['A'] > 0, n_a),
             (lambda args: args['A'] <= 0), n_b)])

print root.decide({'A':5,'B':10})
```

Another approach would be to model your decision tree and then use a code gen that produces the code or write code like below manually yourself:

```
def root(args):
    if args['A'] > 0:
        return n_a(args)

    return n_b(args)

def n_a(args):
    if args['B'] > 0:
        return n_a_a(args)

    return n_a_b(args)

def n_b(args):
    if args['B'] > 5:
        return n_b_a(args)

    return n_b_b(args)

def n_a_a(args):
    return 'y'

def n_a_b(args):
    return 'n'

def n_b_a(args):
    return 'y'

def n_b_b(args):
    return 'n'

print root({'A':5,'B':10})
```

Comment: Your second approach is what I thought at first. But it will calculate slow when there is hundreds of functions or it will be a bad coding I guess. I will try to implement your first suggestion first. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's probably going to be faster than the first approach because the first approach has more indirections etc. and if you use a compiled language much of it's going to be inlined and optimized away by the compiler. Usually if the tree is static having an efficient codegen from a model of the decision tree is going to be the most efficient I'd say.

Comment: Also you can parallelize this pretty easily as long as the functions don't require global state.

Comment: So, which programming language do you suggest to calculate this kind of algorithm? I will try to run it on a server, and this will probably be a Heroku server.

Comment: I don't know. That depends on which languages you know and what your infrastructure is, whether you need certain libraries, whether you have different components that need to fit together etc. I'm a huge fan of Go but I've never written decision trees with it but as a rule of thumb Python tends to be slower than JITted or compiled language except if you use PyPy which actually provides amazing speed compared to CPython.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I will approve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In machine learning terminology, you are describing a *classification tree*.

There are many, many machine learning libraries that implement classification trees. Many of those are designed to be deployed on a server and will have been optimised to score against a built model - which is machine learning terminology for what you're trying to do - efficiently.

However those libraries are usually designed to learn the structure of the tree from training data, whereas you want to build it manually. To use this approach you would need to find a library whose model format you can access and 'fake'. I don't know which one to suggest myself, and it's off topic here to ask for recommendations for a library, but [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help.

One option would be to code your tree in [PMML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) then import this into a platform that can execute PMML models. For example I believe this can be done in SQL Server and/or Microsoft Azure. [This reference](https://medium.com/@aschers/deploy-machine-learning-models-from-r-research-to-ruby-go-production-with-pmml-b41e79445d3d) describes another way of deploying PMML models.

Alternatively you could generate a synthetic data set that displays the rules you want, then train a model on that data using any classification tree library you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked this question in Data Science. I hope they will recommend me something I can understand easily. :)